# Rspec not loading model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my code:

```
require "user"
require "spec_helper"

describe User do

end
```

and spec_helper.rb file

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

user_sprec.rb is located the same folder with spec_helper.rb both inser

```
#{Rails.root}/spec  folder
```

error message I got when i ran "rspec user_spec.rb"

```
usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- user (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /home/li/data/git/mgm/spec/user_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Why are you including `require 'user'`? Check if it works if you remove it

Comment: how does your user.rb look and what is the location of that file?

Comment: @AbM .Thanks after removing `require 'user'` it works now!

Answer (score 0):

RSpec is designed to be run from the project's root directory. I suspect you are running it from within  the `spec` directory, which results in the error you are seeing. Try again from the root directory, passing `spec/user_spec.rb`. Also, the `require user` is superfluous within your spec, since user.rb will be autoloaded as a result of your reference to the `User` constant.